# Why the where clause does not work in the pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given that, I have 2 datasets as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict1 = {
    "A" : range(1,6),
    "B": np.random.randint(1,10,5)
}

dt1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

dict2 = {
    "A" : range(1,6),
    "K" : np.random.randint(3,8,5),
    "Size of Sessile in Words": ["Small","Small","Medium","Large","Medium",]
}

dt2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

I am trying to `join` these 2 dataframes but also use a `Where` clause as well:

```
size = "Small"
dt = dt1.merge(dt2, on='A').query('"Size of Sessile in Words" == {size}'.format(size) )
```

But, it complains with:

```
KeyError: 'size'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `size`? `{size}` requires it to be a dictionary with a `size` key.

Comment: That error is coming from `format()` it has nothing to do with pandas.

Comment: What is `size` in your code above?

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question. i missed a line. Also, the datasets are updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backticks for columns with spaces and use `@size` to use the variable you defined:

```
dt = dt1.merge(dt2, on='A').query('`Size of Sessile in Words`==@size')

   A  B_x  B_y Size of Sessile in Words
0  1    3    5                    Small
1  2    2    5                    Small
```

Comment: Arg.. you got me. :) +1

Comment: Hehehe. We both got it at almost the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `{size}` in the format string means to substitute the value of the `size` key of the dictionary argument. But your argument is a string, not a dictionary, it doesn't have a `size` key. Use `%s` to format a string.

You also need to put quotes around it to use it as a string in the query.

```
dt = dt1.merge(dt2, on='A').query('"Size of Sessile in Words" == "%s"'.format(size) )
```

If you're using Python 3.6 or higher you can use an f-string to substitute directly into the string.

```
dt = dt1.merge(dt2, on='A').query(f'"Size of Sessile in Words" == "{size}"')
```

Comment: Even straightforward `dt.query('"Size of Seissile in Words"== "Small"')` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: when i use this: `dt = dt1.merge(dt2,  on='A').query('"Size of Sessile in Words" == "{}"'.format(size) )` it complains with: `KeyError: False`. Is it successful on your own machine?